How can i hide a Keyboard when clicking on another field?
I have a new inventory screen that lets you create a new inventory, the problem is, when clicking Descripcion a Keyboard appears so you can write, and I already can hide it when clicking outside of it.
To improve the user experience, I want to conceal it when you click on a dropdown menu while the keyboard is up, and I'm unable to figure out how to do it.
This id the code:
class CreateInventory extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateInventory({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CreateInventoryState createState() => _CreateInventoryState();
}

class _CreateInventoryState extends State<CreateInventory> {
  List<String> tiendas = globals.Globals.tiendasList;
  List<String> almacenes = [];
  List<String> tiposInventario = globals.Globals.tiposInventarioList;
  final TextEditingController _dateController = TextEditingController();

  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  final dateFormatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm');
  String? descripcion = '';
  String? selectedTienda='';
  String? selectedAlmacen='';
  String? selectedTipoInventario='';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dateController.text = dateFormatter.format(_selectedDate);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        // Cierra el teclado cuando se toca fuera del TextField
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BuildBottomAppbar(
          descripcion: descripcion,
          selectedAlmacen: selectedAlmacen,
          selectedDate: _selectedDate,
          selectedTienda: selectedTienda,
          selectedTipoInventario: selectedTipoInventario,
        ),
        appBar: buildAppBar(),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                      child: buildContainerDescripcion(),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                      child: buildContainerTienda(),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                      child: buildContainerAlmacen(),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                      child: buildContainerTipoInv(),
                    ),
                    buildContainerFecha(context),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Container buildContainerFecha(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: buildListTileFechaHora(context),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildContainerTipoInv() {
    return Container(
      child: buildListTileTipoInventario(),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildContainerTienda() {
    return Container(
      child: buildListTileTienda(),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildContainerDescripcion() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(  16.0) ,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Descripción',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 17,
            ),
          ),
          buildTextField(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Padding buildTextField() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: TextField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Descripción del inventario',
          ),
          onChanged: (text) {
            setState(() {
              descripcion = text;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildContainerAlmacen() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        color: Colors.grey.shade200,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Almacen',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 17,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          selectedTienda != null&&selectedTienda!=''
              ? buildDropdownMenuAlmacenes()
              : Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 1.0,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Seleccione una tienda',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  ListTile buildListTileFechaHora(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: const Text(
        'Fecha y Hora',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 17,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final DateTime currentTime =
                  DateTime.now(); // Get the current time

                  final DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialDate: currentTime,
                    firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                    lastDate: currentTime, // Set lastDate to current time
                  );
                  if (pickedDate != null) {
                    final TimeOfDay? pickedTime = await showTimePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(currentTime),
                    );

                    if (pickedTime != null) {
                      final DateTime selectedDateTime = DateTime(
                        pickedDate.year,
                        pickedDate.month,
                        pickedDate.day,
                        pickedTime.hour,
                        pickedTime.minute,
                      );

                      if (selectedDateTime.isBefore(currentTime) ||
                          selectedDateTime.isAtSameMomentAs(currentTime)) {
                        // Check if the selected date and time are in the past or equal to the current time
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedDate = selectedDateTime;
                          _dateController.text = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm')
                              .format(_selectedDate);
                        });
                      } else {
                        // Show a message or handle the case where the selected date and time are in the future
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                              title: Text('Invalid Date/Time'),
                              content: Text(
                                  'Please select a date and time that is equal to or earlier than the current time.'),
                              actions: [
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  },
                                  child: Text('OK'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm').format(_selectedDate),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  ListTile buildListTileTipoInventario() {
    return ListTile(
      title: const Text(
        'Tipo de inventario',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 17,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return DropdownMenu<String>(
              width: constraints.maxWidth, // Set DropdownMenu width to the width of the subtitle container
              hintText: 'Selecciona un tipo de inventario',
              onSelected: (String? value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedTipoInventario = value;
                });
              },
              dropdownMenuEntries: tiposInventario
                  .map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
                  value: value,
                  label: value,
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  ListTile buildListTileTienda() {
    return ListTile(
      title: const Text(
        'Tienda',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 17,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return buildDropdownMenuTienda(constraints.maxWidth);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildDropdownMenuAlmacenes() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return DropdownMenu<String>(
            width: constraints.maxWidth,
            hintText: 'Selecciona un almacén',
            onSelected: (String? value) {
              final parts = value?.split('--');
              if (parts!.isNotEmpty) {
                final selectedPart = parts[0];
                setState(() {
                  updateAlmacenesSelect(selectedTienda!);
                  selectedAlmacen = selectedPart;
                });
              }
            },
            dropdownMenuEntries: almacenes
                .map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
                value: value,
                label: value,
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }


  DropdownMenu<String> buildDropdownMenuTienda(double maxWidth) {
    return DropdownMenu<String>(
      width: maxWidth,
      hintText: 'Selecciona una tienda',
      onSelected: (String? value) {
        setState(() {
          selectedTienda = value!;
          updateAlmacenesSelect(selectedTienda!);
        });
      },
      dropdownMenuEntries: tiendas
          .map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(value: value, label: value);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  AppBar buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: const Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Nuevo Inventario',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: AppColors.grisTexto,
                fontFamily: 'Lato',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColors.grisTexto),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }

  Future<void> updateAlmacenesSelect(String s) async {
    if (s.isNotEmpty&&s!='') {
      List<String> value =
      await globals.Globals.filterAlmacenesByTiendaId(s);
      setState(() {
        almacenes = value;
      });
    }
  }
}
class BuildBottomAppbar extends StatelessWidget {
  final DateTime selectedDate;
  final String? descripcion;
  final String? selectedTienda;
  final String? selectedAlmacen;
  final String? selectedTipoInventario;

  BuildBottomAppbar({
    required this.selectedDate,
    required this.descripcion,
    required this.selectedTienda,
    required this.selectedAlmacen,
    required this.selectedTipoInventario,
    Key? key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
      height: 75,
      elevation: 0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'btn1',
              onPressed: () {
                _dialogBuilder(context);
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              child: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'btn2',
              onPressed: () async {
                print('started');
                await uploadInventory();
                print('finished');

              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              child: const Icon(Icons.check),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> uploadInventory() async {
    print('uploading inventory');

    postInventario(
      selectedDate,
      descripcion!,
      // Replace with the appropriate value for idDominio
      selectedTienda!,
      // Replace with the appropriate value for idTienda
      selectedAlmacen!,
      // Replace with the appropriate value for idAlmacen
      selectedTipoInventario!, // Replace with the appropriate value for idTipoInventario
    );
    print('uploaded inventory');

  }

}


Future<void> _dialogBuilder(BuildContext context) {
  return showCupertinoDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text(
          '¿Estás seguro que deseas cancelar la creación de un nuevo inventario?',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        content: Text(
          'Si cancelas, se perderán todos los datos ingresados hasta el momento.',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('Cancelar'),
          ),
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDestructiveAction: true,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('Aceptar'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}


Future<void> postInventario(DateTime fecha, String descripcion, String idTienda,
    String idAlmacen, String idTipoInventario) async {


  InventoryCreatorController inventoryCreatorController =
  InventoryCreatorController();
  String fechaFormateada = await getIds().getFormattedDate(fecha);
  int idTiendaFinal = await getIds.getIdTienda(idTienda);
  int idDominioFinal = await getIds().getIdDomain();
  int idAlmacenFinal = getIdAlmacen(idAlmacen)!;
  int idTipoInventarioFinal =
  await getIds.getIdTipoInventario(idTipoInventario);
  LoginController loginController = LoginController();
  await loginController.updateToken();
  await inventoryCreatorController.postInventario(fechaFormateada, descripcion,
      idDominioFinal, idTiendaFinal, idAlmacenFinal, idTipoInventarioFinal);
}

int? getIdAlmacen(String input) {
  String lastPart = input.split(' ').last;

  // Parse the last part to an integer
  return int.tryParse(lastPart);

}


class getIds {
  MainDbManager mainDbManager = MainDbManager();

  static  Future<int> getIdTipoInventario(String idTipoInventario) async {
    return await MainDbManager.fetchTipoInventarioId(idTipoInventario);
  }

  Future<int> getIdAlmacen(String idAlmacen) async {
    return await MainDbManager.fetchAlmacenId(idAlmacen);
  }

  Future<int> getIdDomain() async {
    return await MainDbManager.fetchDomainId();
  }

  static Future<int> getIdTienda(String idTienda) async {
    return await MainDbManager.fetchTiendaId(idTienda);
  }
  static Future<int>getIdEstadoInventario(String estadoInventario) async {
    return await MainDbManager.fetchEstadoInventarioId(estadoInventario);
  }

  getFormattedDate(DateTime fecha) {
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm').format(fecha);

    return formattedDate;
  }
}



When tap outside TextField you can call  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); to hide keyboard

I already do that. It hides when you click outside. The problem is that it doesn't hide when it's open and you click directly on a dropdown menu.

 FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
            currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
        }


I've tried it, but it still doesn't work for me. I can't hide the keyboard when clicking directly into another interactive field, it just stays open.

Please try this only
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

I added it to the set states of both dropdown menus and still doesn't work, it just keeps the texfield active and the keyboard open if you just click on an interactive field instead of only clicking outside. It hides if you interact with an option INSIDE the dropdown menu, but I need it to close when clicking opening the dropdown menu not when interacting with an option inside.
